# How to make event to be same between api gateway and lambda console test

Tags: amazon-web-services, aws-lambda, aws-api-gateway

When I use lambda console test to test lambda, I found the event I specified in console is different than the event sent from API gateway. The event from API gateway is the complete http request object structure. Below is an example of that.

```
{ resource: '/screenshot',
path: '/screenshot',
httpMethod: 'POST',
headers: null,
multiValueHeaders: null,
queryStringParameters: null,
multiValueQueryStringParameters: null,
pathParameters: null,
stageVariables: null,
requestContext: 
{ path: '/screenshot',
accountId: '286334053171',
resourceId: 'slne19',
stage: 'test-invoke-stage',
domainPrefix: 'testPrefix',
requestId: 'd091e8bf-7948-11e9-951d-3b38e4cc6ad6',
```

But the event is defined in lambda console is just a JSON object. How can I create a same test event in console to mock the API gateway event?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

When you configure a test event in the Lambda Console, you can select from a set of event templates. This includes an API Gateway proxy event:

[image]

If you use this method you'll have to configure the keys for your specific invocation.

Alternatively, you can `console.log` (or language equivalent), the `event` (first argument) argument to the lambda handler. This will give you the precise JSON object that you used in the API Gateway test- without requiring you to edit the template event.